# WP Coda Slider - Not Displaying Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm currently using the plugin WP Coda Slider on the page: http://www.fbct.net/. For some reason the slides are not pulling in the content from the posts, only the titles. I'm using the following template tag on the custom front page:

= read me example =

```
<?php if ( function_exists('c3m_wpcodaslider') ){ 
           c3m_wpcodaslider($id, $cat, $show, $args);} ?>
```

= my code =

```
<?php if ( function_exists('c3m_wpcodaslider') ) {
c3m_wpcodaslider('myslider', '1', '3', 'dynamicArrows:false,autoSlide:false,autoSlideStopWhenClicked:true,dynamicTabsAlign:"left",dynamicTabsPosition:"bottom"');
} ?>
```

When viewing with the inspector all of the classes for the slider are displaying correctly. So I'm not sure why It would pull in the title only and not the rest of the post content. I also tried changing the category and it completely removed the slider, indicating I have the right category. I tried using the short code in a post just to see if the plugin is working..and it worked find. Please help, I'm quite befuddled!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, to get it working I edited the wpcodaslider.php

I replaced line 42 with

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

I don't like having to hack the core plugin file but it seemed to be the only way to get it working.